# Mixing multlined and align

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment, align, multline

I’m trying to have a first equation split on two lines, first one being left aligned, second one right aligned, equation number centered for those two lines, and then a second (numbered) equation that would align at one particular point with a symbol from the second line.

I’ve looked a bit around but couldn’t find a non-manual spacing solution for this case.

Here is what the code would look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{multlined}[.88\linewidth]
        \ce{2CaCO3 + 5C + 2CaC2 + 4H2O + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2CO2} \\
        \ce{&-> 2CaC2 + 3CO2 + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2C2H2 + 2CaCO3 + 2H2O}
    \end{multlined}\\
    \ce{5C + 2H2O &-> CO2 + 2C2H2}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

excepted of course this does not work. If it did, it should look a bit like this:

```
2 CaCO₃ + 5 C + 2 CaC₂ + 4 H₂O + 2 Ca(OH)₂ + 2 CO₂
                         ——⟶ 2 CaC₂ + 3 CO₂ + 2 Ca(OH)₂ + 2 C₂H₂ + 2 CaCO₃ + 2 H₂O
             5 C + 2 H₂O ——⟶ CO₂ + 2 C₂H₂
```

with one equation number for the first two lines, vertically centered, and one equation number for the last line.

This code also provide a manual solution giving roughly the result I expect

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \ce{2CaCO3 + 5C + 2CaC2 + 4H2O& + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2CO2} \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        \ce{&-> 2CaC2 + 3CO2 + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2C2H2 + 2CaCO3 + 2H2O}
    \end{split}\\
    \ce{5C + 2H2O &-> CO2 + 2C2H2}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: working manual example]
But it requires finding manually where to put the first `&` so I’m looking for a more general solution.

I would accept a solution using other environments as long as they match the requirements stated in my first paragraph (e.g. something that left/right align the first equation while using a split for instance).

Comment: Would you mind adding a sketch? I do not seem to understand what the desired output is.

Comment: @JoshuaGonzález Done, also changed a bit the code to avoid some possible confusions.

Comment: @Archange: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygzse.png)?

Comment: @Werner Not really, because I really need the first line to be flushed left and the second one flushed right (here I suspect you just aligned the first line at its right). The reason is that the real equation is longer than one line, hence the split using `multlined`.

Comment: @Archange It's better if you show the actual equation to be typeset or something with no meaning, but whose structure better reflects the original one.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, maybe I minified my example too much you are right. Edited to show actual equation (now the world knows that I do chemistry… while I had a reputation of being a pure physicist ^^).

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it with `split`. The first line is artificially made the same size as the part before the arrow in the last line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\sbox0{\ce{5C + 2H2O}}
\makebox[\wd0][l]{\ce{2CaCO3 + 5C + 2CaC2 + 4H2O + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2CO2}} \\
\ce{&-> 2CaC2 + 3CO2 + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2C2H2 + 2CaCO3 + 2H2O}
\end{split}\\
\ce{5C + 2H2O &-> CO2 + 2C2H2}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I loaded `geometry` because the reactions would not fit in the standard text width of `article`.

Here's how to move the first line to the left margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\def\column@width#1{\ifcase\@xp#1\maxcolumn@widths\fi}
\def\shift@{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    0pt
  \else
    \dimexpr(\displaywidth+\column@width{1}-\column@width{2})/2\relax
  \fi
}
\def\movetoleft#1{%
  &\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{-\shift@}#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\movetoleft{\ce{2CaCO3 + 5C + 2CaC2 + 4H2O + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2CO2}} \\
\ce{&-> 2CaC2 + 3CO2 + 2Ca(OH)2 + 2C2H2 + 2CaCO3 + 2H2O}
\end{split}\\
\ce{5C + 2H2O &-> CO2 + 2C2H2}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not push the second line as right as I would like, but I guess this is because your `\sbox` makes it align left for the bottom line. So I would have to adjust this `\sbox` until it has the right size. At this point I could just much more simply align manually (by using a split too, and putting an & at a guessed/checked place in the first line).

Comment: I’ve added my manual solution to my question and clarification that I’m looking for something general.

Comment: @Archange Does the second version do what you want?

Comment: It’s better, but the second line is not enough flushed to right.

Comment: @Archange Then go forth and do it. I'll stop here. I see no reason for doing like that. And I'd not flush.

Comment: I’ve learned that when you have a too long equation that you need to split in two lines, the first part should be flushed to the left, the second part to the right. Maybe that’s not true, maybe not general, but at least aesthetically it seems better to me than something unequilibrated or too much centered. Anyway thanks for your help, I’ll try to adapt your movetoleft to be able to also movetoright.